# Segfault with getName function c++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am writing a program to find a path in a graph of connected nodes. I have a method that creates the graph from info from a text file. In this method I assign my start and end node pointers to their respective nodes. My `getNodeName` function works fine in this function for all nodes/node pointers. However after I call this function, in `main()` I test `startNode` with `startNode->getNodeName()` it causes a seg fault. In my `createGraph` method I can try this same `cout` and it works perfectly. Is there a reason the `startNode` is not saving after `createGraph` is called? Or is it a different error?

Here is my `Node` class with constructors

```
class Node {
public:
    Node(string newname);
    Node();
    void setNodeName(string newname);
    string getNodeName();
    void attachNewNode(Node *newNode, int direction);
    Node* getAttachedNode(int direction);
    bool isVisited();
    void attachNullNode(int direction);
    bool visited;
    string prevNode;
    void setVisited(bool temp);
private:
    string name;
    Node* attachedNodes[4];
};

Node::Node(string newname) {
    name = newname;
    visited = false;

}

Node::Node() {
    name = "";
    visited = false;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Without seeing `CreateGraph` it is impossible to know why it isn't working, but I suggest that you 1) look at [the help section on minimal complete examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and 2) try a simpler exercise first, such as a linked list.

Comment: I addition, use `vector<Node*> attachedNodes` instead of a primitive array. You might be exceeding the bounds and having undefined behavior because of this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Seg fault in a class C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33557765/seg-fault-in-a-class-c)